# java huffman tree precedence

Tags: java, priority-queue, huffman-code

I have two questions for the following code that I have been researching over the past couple of days. How can I implement the following rules that if there are multiple ties (meaning same number of frequencies) to give single letter groups precedence over multiple letters and then alphabetically? My second question is, could someone point me in the write direction with regards to my code to encode/decode? Should I implement it through my main statement or go ahead and completely write a new class? I am a little stuck on where to start.

```
import java.util.*;


//The following is code that is hardcoded with two separate arrays consisting of
//characters and their corresponding frequency. The application takes in these two
//arrays and constructs a Huffman Encoding Tree. It begins by showing the user the 
//letters, frequency, and the Huffman Code that will be assigned to that letter.
//The application then takes in a .txt file with various strings and encodes them.
//This result is also shown. [still working on this part-- question above]


abstract class HuffmanTree implements Comparable<HuffmanTree> {
public final int frequency; // the frequency of this tree
public HuffmanTree(int freq) { frequency = freq; }

// compares on the frequency
public int compareTo(HuffmanTree tree) {
    return frequency - tree.frequency;
}
}

class HuffmanLeaf extends HuffmanTree {
public final char value; // the character this leaf represents

public HuffmanLeaf(int freq, char val) {
    super(freq);
    value = val;
}
}

class HuffmanNode extends HuffmanTree {
public final HuffmanTree left, right; // subtrees

public HuffmanNode(HuffmanTree l, HuffmanTree r) {
    super(l.frequency + r.frequency);
    left = l;
    right = r;
}
}

public class Huffman {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Symbols that are given to us to hard code
  String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

  //converting string to character array
  char[] letterArray = letters.toCharArray();

  //Frequency of the letters given to us above:
  int[] letterFreqs = {19, 16, 17, 11, 42, 12, 14, 17, 16, 5, 10, 20, 19, 24, 18, 13,
        1, 25, 35, 25, 15, 5, 21, 2, 8, 3};


  // build tree
  HuffmanTree tree = constructTree(letterFreqs,letterArray);

  // print out results
  System.out.println("Letter\tFrequency\tEncoding");
  printCodes(tree, new StringBuffer());
  }




 // input is an array of frequencies and a string of letters
 public static HuffmanTree constructTree(int[] charFreqs, char[] letters) {

   //sets up the priority queue to begin constructing the tree
   PriorityQueue<HuffmanTree> trees = new PriorityQueue<HuffmanTree>();

   //for loop to take in the characters and there frequencies
    for (int i = 0; i < charFreqs.length; i++)
        if (charFreqs[i] > 0)
            trees.offer(new HuffmanLeaf(charFreqs[i], letters[i]));

    assert trees.size() > 0;
    // loop until there is only one tree left
    while (trees.size() > 1) {

        // find the two lowest frequencies
        HuffmanTree a = trees.poll();
        HuffmanTree b = trees.poll();

        // construct a new node and re-insert into queue
        trees.offer(new HuffmanNode(a, b));
    }
    return trees.poll();
}

public static void printCodes(HuffmanTree tree, StringBuffer prefix) {

    assert tree != null;
    if (tree instanceof HuffmanLeaf) {
        HuffmanLeaf leaf = (HuffmanLeaf)tree;

        // print out character, frequency, and code for this leaf (which is just the prefix)
        System.out.println(leaf.value + "\t" + leaf.frequency + "\t" + "\t"  + prefix);


    } else if (tree instanceof HuffmanNode) {
        HuffmanNode node = (HuffmanNode)tree;

        // traverse left
        prefix.append('0');
        printCodes(node.left, prefix);
        prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length()-1);

        // traverse right
        prefix.append('1');
        printCodes(node.right, prefix);
        prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length()-1);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to your first question, you control the ordering in the priority queue via the implementation of `compareTo()`, so I'd do something like the following:

```
abstract class HuffmanTree implements Comparable<HuffmanTree> {
    public final int frequency; // the frequency of this tree

    public HuffmanTree(int freq) {
        frequency = freq;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(HuffmanTree tree) {
        int comparison = frequency - tree.frequency;
        if (0 == comparison) {
            comparison = comparisonTieBreaker(tree);
        }

        return comparison;
    }
    private int comparisonTieBreaker(HuffmanTree tree) {
    int comparison = 0;
    if (this.size() == 1) {
        if (tree.size() == 1) {
            // alphabetical comparison between 2 single-character groups:
            Character.compare(this.firstChar(), tree.firstChar());
        }
        else {
            comparison = -1; // single < multiple
        }
    } else if (tree.size() == 1) {
        comparison = 1; // multiple > single
    }
    return comparison;
}

public abstract int size();

public abstract char firstChar();
}
```

As for the two abstract methods, in a `HuffmanLeaf`, `size()` returns 1 and `firstChar()` returns its character. In a `HuffmanNode`, `size()` returns `left.size() + right.size()` (basic recursion) and `firstChar()` can return `left.firstChar()`, although `firstChar()` will normally never be called on a `HuffmanNode`.

In response to your second question, I think you should have `encode()` and `decode()` methods, either in the `Huffman` class itself or in another class. You can obviously call them from the main, but I'd pull out of the main method anything which could be re-used elsewhere.

Edit: You asked me to elaborate.  Your second question was not so clear, but it seems like you're stuck on how to proceed with encoding and decoding.  I would start by adding to `HuffmanTree` methods `toMapForDecoding()` and `toMapForEncoding()`, each of which returns a Map (it's basically the same map for both methods but with keys and values inversed).  These maps (to be used in your `encode()` and `decode()` methods) allow constant-time conversion between an input symbol and an (encoded or decoded) output symbol. The implementation of these methods can be quite similar to what you've already done in `printCodes()`. As for where to put the `encode()` and `decode()` methods, don't be blocked by that.  Put them where it's convenient for you and then move them later if you need to.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I am a little confused on how to implement this.

Comment: For my response to your first question I provided a lot of details, so if you understand generally how the result of compareTo() affects the ordering in the PriorityQueue, and if you understand recursion (which seems to be the case, since you use it in your code) it should be clear.

Comment: so i got the encode to work, but i am confused on how you would search through the string of encoded 0s and 1s and find a match in the map? to be clearer, say your given 010101 where the answer should be xy (x = 010, y = 101), how would you find those in the map?

Comment: Each encoding is unique, so maybe  you try "0", and if it's not in the map you try "01", and if it's not in the map you try "010", etc. until you find the matching symbol.  Then you start over with the next 0 or 1 in the sequence.